# How to start SSH service right after Termux app installed?

Tags: android, termux

Thanks to [termux-packaging](https://github.com/termux/termux-packaging), I could make a custom bootstrap.zip that had openssh installed.

But I want to run some commands (like sshd to start ssh service) right after TermuxInstaller setup thread finished.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: How about adding that to the bash.bashrc of your custom bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the ssh Command you want to run to the bash.bashrc file of your bootstrap...afaik..that should do the trick